# Taking more time for svn ci/commit

Tags: 14.04, ssh, svn

I am doing a real time project. The base i.e source code size is very huge i.e more than 6GB. While i am trying to do `svn commit` these files, using `ssh` , it takes more than 1 or 2 hour time to get a password. The process of Adding files is happened without any trouble. After giving commit command only, it is taking more and more time. So, i want to know that Is there any file size issue..?, Is any problem with `ssh`..? and Is there any way to protect Pipe Broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an svn changelist to keep track of a set of files that you want to commit together.

The linked page goes into lots of details, but here's an executive summary example:

```
$ svn changelist my-changelist mydir/dir1/file1.c mydir/dir2/myfile1.h
$ svn changelist my-changelist mydir/dir3/myfile3.c etc.
... (add all the files you want to commit together at your own rate)
$ svn commit -m"log msg" --changelist my-changelist
```